# Site background image centered and fixed?

Tags: css, background, position

I'm working on a site that has a fixed width div that is centered and I wanted to have two designs on either side of the div which I was able to get using two divs. The issue is the way I did it, those images add to the site width, causing a horizontal scroll bar to appear if the window is too small. Even though the whole content div fits with in the screen.

CSS

```
.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
}

.span {
    margin-right: 0;
    width: 500px;
}

.logo {
    margin-top: 25px;
}

.logo-img {
    height: 60px;
    left: -21px;
    position: relative;
}

.swirls {
    height: 0px;
}

.left-swirls {
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    right: 100px;
    width: 188px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.right-swirls {
    position: relative;
    top: -50px;
    left: 215px;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.nav {
    background-color: #0ff;
}

.content {
    background-color: #00f;
    height: 200px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="span logo">
            <img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img839/2507/logongv.png" class="logo-img"/>
        </div>
        <div class="span swirls">
            <img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img831/3254/leftswirls.png" class="left-swirls" />
            <img src="http://imageshack.us/a/img600/7424/rightswirls.png" class="right-swirls" />
        </div>
    <div class="span last nav">
        Nav Bar
    </div>
    <div class="span content">
        Body content
    </div>
</div>
```

An example of the issue can be viewed here: http://jsfiddle.net/e4j6b/8/

I'm trying to get the background image(s) centered relative to the div instead of the sides of the browser.

Is there a way to center a background image just like a div with margin: 0 auto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want .left-swirls and .right-swirls to not add to the width of the document, then they should be background images. (For modern browsers, multiple background images work fine.)

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/MbGSP/1/

```
body {
  background: url(http://imageshack.us/a/img831/3254/leftswirls.png) center center no-repeat,
              url(http://imageshack.us/a/img600/7424/rightswirls.png) center center no-repeat;
}
```

You can center background images, both horizontally and vertically, with `center center` for the positions.

Comment: That is correct I was trying to get them as background images but there is an issue with doing that. If the browser is expanded the images hug the edges since they are left and right positioned instead of being positioned relative to the main content div.

Comment: Background images is the best solution for preventing them from affecting the flow of your document.  How do you want the images to behave in differently-sized windows?  You can specify background images on any element, and change the positioning to be in pixels or % instead of left or center.

Comment: I want the background image to hug the div at all times but if they resize the browser window so it's just fits the content div there wont be a horizontal scroll bar. In my example if you adjust the width of the frame you'll see the "background images" stay with the content div. Is it possible to center a background image on the page so it lines up with a div that is set with margin: 0 auto;?

Comment: You can center a bg image, both horizontally and vertically, with `center center` for the positions.

Comment: NP - If you update your question to clarify what you were looking for in the end, I can update my question and fiddle.

Comment: Alright the question has been updated. That way you're answer can correlate with it better.